# Accessing Java Applets on website in iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, java

Is there any way, **without jailbreaking**, to open java applets  on websites on an iPhone?

I want to open a java based online ssh service (applet) : http://www.cryptzone.com/products/agmindterm/

I will be using it from Usermin (Webmin).

Is there a **free** solution?

Comment: You mean: running java applets on the iPhone?

Answer (score 6):

Java applets are not supported on iOS.

Comment: Is there absolutely NO WAY whatsoever to open applets like the above?

Comment: Applets will NOT work. There might be solutions that use Java **Script**, but that is a whole different world and would require programming on your end.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to use a cloud browser or a VNC client to your PC.